# Flutter/Dart - Dropdown value not changing

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created a dropdown menu and populated it with values however, when I select one, the selected value doesn't change. I know this is a common issue on SO but I have tried many solutions, none of which have helped. Here is my code:

```
  String selectedOccasion;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final collectionProvider = Provider.of<CollectionProvider>(context).allOccasions;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
        title: Text('Viewer'),
        actions: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () {
                    showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: Text("Add to collection"),
                            content: DropdownButton<String>(
                              hint: Text('Select Occasion'),
                              value: selectedOccasion,
                              items: collectionProvider.map((String value) {
                                return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: value,
                                  child: new Text(value),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                              onChanged: (String newValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  selectedOccasion = newValue;
                                });
                              },),
                          );
                        });
                  })
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(child: Text('Body')
    );
  }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: try to set a default value in selectedOccasion ( one of the array values )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert DropdownButton to a stateful widget. so setState will work. all other code will work fine.

```
   StatefulBuilder(
                  builder: (context, setState) {
                    DropdownButton()
                  })
```

Comment: Do I still need to do this even though my page is a stateful widget? Thanks

Comment: yes, setState called inside dropdown will update the whole page instead of DropdownButton, so you need to wrap it with statefulbuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Here a example of accepted response.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> listValues = ['Height (inch)', 'Height (cm)'];
    final borderRadiusDropdown = BorderRadius.circular(14);
    const textColorItem = Colors.black;
    String dropdownValue = listValues.first;

    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setInnerState) => DropdownButton<String>(
        //internal state for custom dropdown button
        value: dropdownValue,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: textColorItem,
            fontSize: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.fontSize),
        borderRadius: borderRadiusDropdown,
        underline: const SizedBox(),
        elevation: 9,
        onChanged: (String? value) {
          setInnerState(() {
            dropdownValue = value!;
          });
        },
        items: listValues.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```